# Imam Mehandi A man is saying that he is Isa and there is no mehandi he lives In India, Aurangabaad.

Tags: imam-mahdi

There is a man name Shakeel bin haneef and one of friend is a supporter of him.
And he always wants debate from me but I can't because I don't have that much knowledge. 
So please provide me some hadiths which can prove him wrong. 
He always says there is no imam mehendi but Isa it is written in ibn e Maja authentic hadiths. 
Please provide me some authentic hadiths with reference
So that I can have debate on this topic and get my friend back on the right path.

Answer (score 3):

> A man is saying that he is Isa and there is no mehandi he lives In India, Aurangabaad.

'Isa Alayhi Salam will arrive after Dajjal and as you can see from the real world, Dajjal has not emerged so that means Prophet 'Isa is not here on earth yet. Furthermore, 'Isa will descend in Damascus, not in India. This is sufficient for you to know that he is not 'Isa.

The Prophet said, "Jesus son of Marry will descend at the white minaret to the east of Damascus" - Sunan Abi Dawud (4321). Read the rest of the hadith here showing Dajjal will already be here and 'Isa will catch up with him: https://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/31

As for this man's claim on Mahdi not being real, Muslims have believed in Al Mahdi for centuries since the Prophet (ﷺ) told us about him til today. This person you mentioned is both ***rejecting Islamic texts*** AND *going against the consensus of the Muslim Ummah*.

There are plenty of evidences that the Mahdi is real (per the Sunnah). Such numerous narrations from so many different narrators that the scholars say these hadith reach the level of Tawatur (guaranteed authentic; impossible to be wrong). You may read here for a list of the hadith about Imam Al Mahdi: [(IslamQA)](https://islamqa.info/en/1252).

From IslamQA

> 1. Abu Sa’eed al-Khudri reported that the Messenger of Allaah (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) said: "At the end of the time of my ummah, the Mahdi will appear. Allaah will grant him rain, the earth will bring forth its fruits, he will give a lot of money, cattle will increase and the ummah will become great. He will rule for seven or eight years. (Mustadrak al-Haakim, 4/557-558; he said: this is a hadeeth whose isnaad is saheeh, although it was not reported by al-Bukhaari and Muslim. Al-Dhahabi agreed with him, and al-Albaani said: this is a saheeh sanad, and its men are thiqaat (trustworthy), Silsilat al-ahaadeeth al-saheehah, vol. 2, p. 336, hadeeth 771)
> 2. ‘Ali (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "The Messenger of Allaah (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) said: ‘The Mahdi is one of us, a member of my family. Allaah will guide him in a single night.’" (Musnad Ahmad, 2/58, hadeeth 645, edited by Ahmad al-Shaakir, who said: its isnaad is saheeh; Sunan Ibn Maajah, 2/1367. This hadeeth was also classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’ al-Sagheer, 6735). Ibn Katheer said: "This means that Allaah will forgive him, grant him help, inspire him and guide him, when he was not like this before." (Al-Nihaayah, al-Fitan wa’l-Malaahim, 1/29; edited by Taha Zayni).
> 3. Abu Sa’eed al-Khudri said: "The Messenger of Allaah (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) said: ‘The Mahdi is of my lineage, with a high forehead and a long, thin, curved nose. He will fill the earth with fairness and justice as it was filled with oppression and injustice, and he will rule for seven years.’" (Sunan Abi Dawud, Kitaab al-Mahdi, 11/375, hadeeth 4265; Mustadrak al-Haakim, 4/557; he said: this is a saheeh hadeeth according to the conditions of Muslim, although it was not reported by al-Bukhaari and Muslim. See also Saheeh al-Jaami, 6736).
> 4. Umm Salamah said: "I heard the Messenger of Allaah (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) say: ‘The Mahdi is of my lineage and family, from the descendants of Faatimah.’" (Sunan Abu Dawud, 11/373; Sunan Ibn Maajah. 2/1368. Al-Albaani said that it is saheeh in Saheeh al-Jaami, 6734)
> 5. Jaabir (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "The Messenger of Allaah (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) said: ‘‘Eesaa ibn Maryam will descend, and their leader the Mahdi will say, "Come and lead us in prayer," but he will say, "No, one of them should lead them as an honour to this ummah from Allaah."’" The version narrated by Muslim says: "… Then ‘Eesaa ibn Maryam (Peace be upon him) will descend and their leader will say, ‘Come and lead us in prayer,’ but he will say, ‘No, some of you are leaders over others as an honour from Allaah to this ummah.’" (Reported by Muslim, 225)
> 6. Abu Sa’eed al-Khudri (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "The Messenger of Allaah (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) said: "He is one of us, behind whom ‘Eesaa ibn Maryam will pray." (Reported by Abi Na’eem in Akhbaar al-Mahdi. Al-Albaani said it is saheeh; see al-Jaami’ al-Sagheer, 5/219, hadeeth 5796).
> 7. ‘Abdullaah ibn Mas’ood reported that the Prophet (Peace & Blessings of Allaah be upon Him) said: "The world will not come to an end until the Arabs are ruled by a man from my family whose name will be the same as mine." (Musnad Ahmad, 5/199, hadeeth 3573. Another version says: "… whose name is the same as mine and whose father’s name is the same as my father’s." Sunan Abi Dawud, 11/370).

Comment: Sir you have replied correct or not I don't know please can you prove it by authentic hadiths because they will give you proper authentic reference so please give me some proper authentication.

Comment: I gave you the link to many, many hadith on the Mahdi being real: https://islamqa.info/en/1252 Please read them there.